# NFC Tag emulated by Android phone triggers Apple Wallet

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, hce, apple-wallet

I am working on an android app that emulates NFC Tag (HCE Host-Card Emulation), so other devices can read NDEF messages. Whenever if I approach the android device to iPhone, it sometimes shows the Apple Wallet app automatically. Basic NFC tags do not trigger Apple Wallet. Is there any way to prevent showing Apple Wallet by HCE? How can I change this behavior?

Update:

Any NFC available android phone can trigger Apple Wallet if NFC functionality is enabled and approach to iPhone (without emulation of HCE, just an android phone itself).

Comment: @FarmanAliKhan I used apple pay suppression when the app is open. You need to get permission from Apple for the suppression